# How to define strings in Typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have this array of Projects where stack has multiple strings

```
const projects: IProject[] = [
    {name: '', description: '', stack: {'php', 'sql'}}
  ]
```

How will the interface be or what is the best approach?

```
interface IProject {
  name: string
  description: string
  stack: 
  repo?: string
  url?: string
}
```

I tried to declare another interface IStack[] but I don't want another array of key value pairs as it increases my code

```
stack: [
{name: 'react'}, {name: 'graphql'}
]
```

Comment: Can't you just use an array of string ? `stack: ['php', 'sql']` and `string[]` type

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without any typos. You might want to test it in an IDE to see where the problems are. Right now this is syntactically invalid in multiple places and therefore it's not clear exactly what you're asking. Good luck!

Comment: type StackItem = "php"|"sql"|"react-native"; ... stack: StackItem[]

Comment: `stack: {'php', 'sql'}` is not valid JS/TS syntax. What is the `stack` value actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood I hope your approach in creating string `Set` for stack

Simply use `stack: Set<string>;`

```
interface IProject {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  stack: Set<string>;
  repo?: string;
  url?: string;
}
```

Then you can use your code like this

```
const project: IProject = {
  name: 'Project Name';
  description: 'Description';
  stack: new Set(['php', 'sql']);
}
```

And then the result will be as bellow screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you, though this wasn't the expected solution but it actually helped me after digging deeper into the Set Methods of add() and has() which I weren't aware off.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a fixed set of strings, you can use a union type:

```
type Stack = "php" | "sql" | "react";

interface Project {
  stack: Stack[];
}

const project: Project = {stack: ["php", "sql"]};
```

Otherwise if you just want an array of random strings, you can use `stack: string[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use in string array:

```
interface IProject {
  name: string
  description: string
  stack: string[]
  repo?: string
  url?: string
}
```

and the object is:

```
const projects: IProject[] = [
    {name: '', description: '', stack: ['php', 'sql']}
  ]
```